# How to get latitude and longitude with a custom GeoPointer

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, geopoints

I have a GPS map and want to use a custom geopoint (using a my PNG) that when I click on a place in the map returns latitude and longitude.

Searching I have found this code

```
public void recieveLongClick(MotionEvent ev)

    {
        Projection p = mapView.getProjection();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = p.fromPixels((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
        // You can now pull lat/lng from geoPoint
    }
```

But I don't know how to use this and how to define a GeoPointer with a custom image that is showed when someone click on a place in the map.

Comment: check it once:   http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/53/Integrating+Google+Maps+in+Android+App/

Comment: thank you but the sample in the site linked doesn't work: crash every time with a NullPointer Exception when ItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem); is invoked